# How to take action when user closes mobile browser window?

Tags: javascript, jquery, signalr

I've been using these two, which mostly work well:

```
$(window).on('beforeunload', function() {});

$(window).on('unload', function() {});
```

I use SignalR, and these trigger a function on the server which removes a record in a database. However, investigating the database when the page is live reveals that some records do not get removed. I also know I've got quite a few mobile users. Could there be a problem with mobile browsers not triggering these events? I hope there is something I can do to fix this.

Comment: I've never used SignalR, but you could you reverse your logic? every connection ends with trigger this function in 5 minutes, if it's already pending, clear the pending and reset the timer. Would that solve the problem?

Comment: It doesn't really seem like it relates to SignalR. The page works something like this: User clicks a button, SignalR tells server to insert record. User clicks other button, SignalR tells server to remove record. BUT, in case user doesn't click other button, but instead closes his browser tab, the record still has to be removed. This has worked on every desktop browser I've tried. I suspect it has something to do with the fact that some users use their phone. I might be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The term "closes mobile browser window" can mean many things...

1. The user actually closes the tab (or all tabs)...
2. The user closes the browser app (by swiping the app off the recent apps or by closing all recent apps)...
3. System closes browser process (due to low memory or some other reason)...

etc.

Not all these actions may trigger the `beforeunload` or `unload` events in the browser tab and unfortunately, you do not have any way to intercept some these actions

Your only viable option is to perhaps look into other ways of doing what you are trying to accomplish with the `unload` events...

Comment: I would presume that nr 1 triggers it, because the browser app has full control and can notify all tabs. Nr 2 should trigger it as well If the app is closed normally, I would think a SIGTERM message (at least on Android) is sent to the app and that the browser then notifies each tab, as it has full control now as well. Nr 3. on the other hand I would think is an exception, as the app can't take action, but this is so rare that I don't need to take that into consideration at the moment. I don't see any reason why the function should not get called at 1 and 2. Am I completely of the charts here?